# C# - Filtering form objects (e.g. textbox) for times

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How in C# forms can you filter (for example a textbox) in the following format (for time)

XX:XX

24 hour clock

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? Validate after the user entered the data? Or do you want a control that only allows certain values/pattern to be entered?

Comment: Do you mean parse instead of filter?

Comment: @Oded Excuse my lack of.. I am referring to filtering, rather than validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox` control.